# using Selenium to close the browser after finishing the loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have the script below to scrape data from iHerbs.
However, even when I put the `driver.close()` so it could stop after the 24th item but it still keeps scraping the data and won't stop.

any solution to stop the loop and close the browser after finishing the 24th item.

Thank you so much!

please check the script as below:

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://ca.iherb.com/c/Vitamins?noi=24")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    
    
    
    
    #close the pop up
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"svg[data-ga-event-action='list-close']"))).click()
    
    #store all the links in a list
    item_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".absolute-link-wrapper > a.product-link")))]
    
    
    review_titles= list()
    review_contents = list()
    product_helpful= list() 
    product_not_helpful = list()
    member_rating = list()
    total_rate = list()
    
    
    #iterate over the links
    for item_link in item_links:
        driver.get(item_link)
    
        #locate and click on the `View All Reviews` link
        all_reviews_link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.all-reviews-link > a")))
        x = all_reviews_link.get_attribute("href")
        
        MAX_PAGE_NUM = 2
    
        for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
            page_num = str(i)
            url = x +'?&p='+ page_num 
            print(url)    
            driver.get(url)
            review_containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('review-row')
                   
            for containers in review_containers:
                total_rate.append(driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-i36p8g').text)       
                review_contents.append(containers.find_element_by_class_name('review-text').text)
                product_helpful.append(containers.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="Helpful"] span').text)
                product_not_helpful.append(containers.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="Unhelpful"] span').text)
                stars = containers.find_elements_by_class_name("css-172co2l")
                rating = 0
                for star in stars:
                    star_color = star.find_element_by_tag_name("path").get_attribute("fill")
                    #print(star_color)
                    if star_color != "transparent":
                        rating += 1
                member_rating.append(rating)
                
        time.sleep(5) #slow the script down
    
   driver.close()
```

Comment: try `driver.close()` instead `browser.close()`

Comment: yeah thank you but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `driver.quit()`. This closes all browsers that were opened with Selenium. The `.close()` closes one browser opened with Selenium. Both still work but if the latter does not, then try the former.

For more details, you can view this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/how-do-i-close-the-browser-window-at-the-end-of-a-selenium-test)

Answer (score 0):

import:

```
import os
```

delete "browser.close()" and add

```
os.system("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: but it didnt work out and it kept fetching more pages randomly